# Как передать данные в форму Python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать данные в форму:

https://fedresurs.ru/messages/IsSearching
необходимо выбрать ЮЛ
При нажатии открывается новая форма. 
Тип сообщения я выбираю так:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_ddlMessageTypeList'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии')

s = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch"]') #Кнопка поиск
s.click()
```

ЮЛ хотел выбрать так:

```
s = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_txtCode').send_keys('555')
```

Но получаю ошибку, что элемент ctl00_MainContent_txtCode не найден.

Подскажите как правильно?

Попробовал так:

```
s = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="ctl00_MainContent_sfCompanySelector_txtObjectName"]') #находим строку поиска ЮЛ, клик
s.click()
```

Находим input для ввода ИНН

```
i = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#aspnetForm > div.extsearch > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)')
i.send_keys('4444444444')
```

Ошибка

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#aspnetForm > div.extsearch > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)"}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
```

получилось так, только теперь я не захожу на 10, 20, 30 стр ... создается файлик с кодом страницы, 7,8,9, 11.. часть кода использующая selenium не моя, кто может объяснить почему я пропускаю эти страницы?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_list(n):  # n page number
    timeout = 3
    try:
        # waiting for the paginator to have current page as class "active" li with span
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="active"]/a/span[text()="{}"]'.format(n)))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    # looking for record names and record authors
    lst_divs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('display-field.message-in-list')
    lst_as = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "ctl00_MainContent_lvMessageList_ctrl")]')

    for d, a in zip(lst_divs, lst_as):
        print('\t{} :: {}'.format(d.text, a.text))


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")
url = 'http://fedresurs.ru/messages/IsSearching'

driver.get(url)

while True:
    # getting last page
    a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.right > table.paging td > ul > li:last-child')
    last_page = int(a.text)
    # print(last_page)
    # go over first page
    # print('Page {}'.format(last_page-9))
    get_list(last_page-9)

    # loop thru other pages
    for i in range(last_page-9, last_page):

        # print('Page {}'.format(i + 1))

        if i < 11:
            link = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$ucTopDataPager$ctl00$ctl{0:02d}','')".format(i)
            # print('1 vetka ' + str(i))
        else:
            link = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$ucTopDataPager$ctl00$ctl{0:02d}','')".format(int(str(i)[-1])+1)
            # print('2 vetka ' + str(int(str(i)[-1]) + 1) + 'page ' + str(i))


        # finding next page

        a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="{}"]'.format(link))

        # click, wait + parse
        a.click()
        # getting page
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        out = open('Page_{}'.format(i) + '.txt', 'w')
        out.writelines(soup.prettify())
        # print('Printing page {}'.format(i))
        time.sleep(5)
        get_list(i + 1)

    np = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.paging td:last-child a')

    if np.text == '...':
        np.click()
        # element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="active"]/a/span[text()="{}"]'.format(last_page + 1)))
        # WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(element_present)
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        break

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_sfCompanySelector_txtObjectName').click
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_txtName")))
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_txtName').send_keys('555')
```

Главным образом обратить надо внимание на `wait.until`, т.к. *необходимо дождаться появления элемента на странице*.